# Swift dismiss UISheetPresentationController in compact height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisheetpresentationcontroller

I am using a UISheetPresentationController to show a bottom sheet in an iOS app.

In compact height the sheet goes to fullScreen which is the desired behavior.  However I cannot dismiss it without adding a custom dismiss button.

Is there a default implementation of a dismiss button in full screen for the UISheetPresentationController similar to what can be seen on the ActivityViewController?

The ActivityViewController shows an xmark button to dismiss when in fullScreen mode on compact height.